# Django: Advanced StringAgg with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, orm, string-agg

## Setup

I have two tables:

**Person**

| name |
| --- |
| Tim |
| Tom |
| Tam |

**Pet**
| species | color |
|---------|-------|
| Cat     | black |
| Dog     | brown |

And a ManyToMany that connects them:

**PersonToPet**

| Person.name | Pet.species |
| --- | --- |
| Tim | Cat |
| Tim | Dog |
| Tom | Cat |

## Desired result

Using Django, I would like to annotate Person such that I get this table:

| Person.name | result |
| --- | --- |
| Tim | <a>Cat (black)</a><a>Dog (brown)</a> |
| Tom | <a>Cat (black)</a> |
| Tam |  |

Is this possible?

I've only got this:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg


Person.objects.annotate(
    result=StringAgg('pets', delimiter=',')
)
```

Which gives:

| Person.name | result |
| --- | --- |
| Tim | Cat,Dog |
| Tom | Cat |
| Tam |  |

Can anyone crack this nut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, F, Value, CharField


Person.objects.annotate(
    result=StringAgg(
        Case(
            When(
                pets__isnull=False,
                then=Concat(
                    # <a>{species} ({color})\<a> 
                    Value('<a>'),
                    F('pet__species'),
                    Value(' ('),
                    F('pet__color'),
                    Value(')</a> '),
                    output_field=CharField()
                )
            )
        ),
        delimiter=''
    )
)
```